# Python mock переменной внутри функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, mock

У меня есть функция следующего толка:

```py
def foo1():
    data = foo2() # возвращает список словарей
    top10 = sorted(data, key=lambda _переменная_, reverse=True)[:10]
    ...
```

Мне нужно провести юнит-тест на результат foo1, но foo2 отрабатывает долго. Как мне сделать так, чтобы в тесте переменная data в foo1 заполнялась определенным образом?

Comment: Можно изменить функцию `foo1` так, что она будет не сама получать данные  из `foo2`, а получать данные через аргумент, тогда ее будет проще тестировать.

Answer (score 3):

После импорта модуля ты можешь манипулировать его объектами как тебе угодно. Например подменить оригинальный метод своим в коде теста.

```
import unittest

import module


def test_foo2():
    return []


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp():
        module.foo2 = test_foo2

    def test_foo(self):
        result = module.foo1()
        self.assertTrue(False)


if __name__ in "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Этот вариант не позволит тебе протестировать оригинальный foo2, тогда можно делать подмену в методе теста и возвращать все назад.